actix-web return err from middleware
I am trying to return err from my auth middleware with actix-web 4.9.0.
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct AuthConfig {
    token: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct AuthFactory {
    config: AuthConfig,
}

impl AuthFactory {
    pub fn new(config: AuthConfig) -> Self {
        Self { config }
    }
}

impl<S, B> Transform<S, ServiceRequest> for AuthFactory
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type InitError = ();
    type Transform = AuthHiMiddleware<S>;
    type Future = Ready<Result<Self::Transform, Self::InitError>>;

    fn new_transform(&self, service: S) -> Self::Future {
        ready(Ok(AuthHiMiddleware {
            service,
            config: self.config.clone(),
        }))
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct AuthHiMiddleware<S> {
    service: S,
    config: AuthConfig,
}

impl<S, B> Service<ServiceRequest> for AuthHiMiddleware<S>
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = LocalBoxFuture<'static, Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>>;

    forward_ready!(service);

    fn call(&self, req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
        let mut authenticate_pass = false;

        let either = if !authenticate_pass {
            Either::Left(req.into_response(HttpResponse::Forbidden().body("Forbidden")))
        } else {
            Either::Right(self.service.call(req))
        };

        Box::pin(async move {
            let a = match either {
                Either::Left(res) => Ok(res),
                Either::Right(fut) => Err(fut.await),
            };
            a
        })
    }
}

I got an  complex error message:
expected `{async block@quant-nx/src/core/live/middleware/mod.rs:87:18: 87:28}` to be a future that resolves to `Result<ServiceResponse<B>, Error>`, but it resolves to `Result<ServiceResponse, Result<ServiceResponse<B>, Error>>`
expected enum `Result<ServiceResponse<B>, actix_web::Error>`
   found enum `Result<ServiceResponse<BoxBody>, Result<ServiceResponse<B>, actix_web::Error>>`

It looks like I just need to get part of the Result but I dont think that I use Either in a proper way. Any idea?
I have tried to search for recent actix-web middleware examples. It seems that there are only outdated results for old actix-web version.
PS: There is a token in the config. I need to verify part of each request against the token.

I highly recommend using from_fn to craft your middleware if at all possible

It seems like you're unnecessarily wrapping the right variant, which already returns Result, in another Result. I.e. I think the match should be match either { Either::Left(res) => Ok(res), Either::Right(fut) => fut.await, }.
